# How to execute JPA code out side spring transaction

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to optimize read-only queries, So I want to execute JPQL query outside of transaction so that entities returned from JPQL will not be managed in current persistence context (To save the cost of dirty checking and unnecessary managing those entities to save 2X size in persistence context).

I tried below,

```
@Repository
public class CustomPostRepository {

  @Autowired
  private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;


  @Transactional
  public void foo() {
      // Some other transactional code (read-write) here ...

      final TransactionStatus transactionStatus = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus(); // returns current active transaction
      System.out.println("transactionStatus.isNewTransaction() = " + transactionStatus.isNewTransaction()); // returns TRUE

      List<Post> posts = employeeRepository.bar();

     // Some other code here...
  }
}


@Repository
public class CustomJpaEmployeeDao implements EmployeeRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public List<Post> bar() {
        // Ideally this method should throw Exception, as transaction is expected to be suspended (not exists here)
        final TransactionStatus transactionStatus = TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus();

        final List<Post> post = em.createNamedQuery("Post.findAllForReporing", Post.class).getResultList();
        System.out.println("entityManager.contains(post) = " + em.contains(post.get(0))); // returns true, which should be false

        return post;
    }
}
```

Caller,

```
@Test
public void jpqlTest() {
    customPostRepository.foo();
}
```

I want to execute `EmployeeRepository#bar` outside of transaction (created by C`ustomPostRepository#bar`), but `Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED` is not working and all selected entities from JPQL are managed in the current persistence context.

So, is there any way to avoid managing those entities or executing code outside of the transaction? or is something missing here?

Comment: Can you explain what the term *uncommitted read* means?

Comment: You would have to remove all `@Transactional` annotations.

Comment: @Andronicus, but I want to execute other code in method CustomPostRepository#foo in a read-write transaction. I tried removing Transactional annotation on CustomJpaEmployeeDao#bar but em.contains(post.get(0) still returns true. (maybe even after removing Transactional annotation entityManager proxy in CustomJpaEmployeeDao is referring to one already attached at current thread)

Comment: But when you're returning from method, the transaction is closed. What is the difference? Besides `EntityManager#contains` is no way to check is an entity is managed,

Comment: As CustomJpaEmployeeDao#bar is called from CustomPostRepository#foo, the transaction is created by CustomPostRepository#foo and not byCustomJpaEmployeeDao#bar, so transaction will end when CustomPostRepository#foo ends and not CustomJpaEmployeeDao#bar , so entities returned (posts) will be still managed inside method CustomPostRepository#foo (caller), which I don't want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove `@Transactional` annotation. In this case it won't make a difference unless the method itself doesn't throw `LazyInitializationException`. If there was a case where transaction was needed, you would have to create a separate method for it / call it from the same bean, so that no proxy is created.

Also `EntityManager#contains` does not check, if the process runs within transaction or entities are dirty-checked.

If you don't want to / can't change those methods, use `EntityManager#detach`.

Comment: yes, I think I will have to use EntityManager#detach to manually detach entities.